# Is there a range of VARCHAR2 which can be automatically convert to NUMBER in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, varchar2

There is a ***plsql*** Cursor like below.

```
CURSOR get_customer_balance(cust_id_ IN VARCHAR2) IS
      SELECT t.cust_balance
      FROM customer_tab t
      WHERE t.customer_id =cust_id_;
```

**Procedure Body**

```
OPEN  get_customer_balance(123456789);
FETCH get_customer_balance INTO balance_;
CLOSE get_customer_balance;
```

*In customer_tab, customer_id is a number type colomn. even through cursor parameter is varchar2 this works fine. for some values this give an error. also any error will be occurred in runtime only.*

> Is there a ***range of varchar2*** that can automatically ***converted to
> number?***

Comment: Are you asking what are the minimum/maximum values that would apply for an alpha-numeric value to be converted to a numeric value?  If so, then you can read about data-types here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-F6309DF8-162F-48A4-9454-FEE59EC6644F

Comment: It's completely unclear why you need to declare the procedure this way, and now you are trying to solve the problem that was introduced by yourself. Don't use type X to pass a value of type Y: use the same data types or at least use explicit type cast to avoid NLS settings issue

Comment: @astentx I wanted to know why it worked at the first place for some values. I though there is a some kind of a range that text can be convert to number. it seems there is no range but for some values it can be converted. see the answer given by Littlefoot

Comment: Short example of why such range doesn't exist: `'1' < '4 seasons' < '7',` where only the smallest and largest can be converted to numbers.

Comment: @LahiruGamage Because for *some* (I cannot guess which since you haven't posted any examples of success/failure cases) values implicit conversion may convert a value and for some it cannot. I don't know your NLS settings, but you may take some failed value and see its implicitly converted value with `select to_char(value) from dual`. Things get more complicated when you execute the code in background job, where database parameters are used

Answer (score 2):

> In customer_tab, `customer_id` is a **number** type colomn

vs.

> `CURSOR get_customer_balance(cust_id_ IN VARCHAR2) IS`

means that you **intentionally** do things **wrong**.

Not only that you should have passed a `number` - as a matter of fact, you should have passed `customer_tab.customer_id%type` so cursor declaration would have been

```
CURSOR get_customer_balance(cust_id_ IN customer_tab.customer_id%type) IS
```

---

As of your question: Oracle will try to **implicitly** convert any datatype you pass to a valid number. Sometimes it'll succeed (if you pass `'10'`, for example), sometimes not (`'ABC'` or `'15XF4'`). There's no "range"; it just depends on actual value.

---

If you want, have a look at Tom Kyte's <a=href="https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/on-implicit-conversions-and-more">On implicit conversions and more, saying - among other things:

> The problem is in your code. Your developers have programmed a very nasty bug, and the bug is called “implicit conversions.”

Comment: This is the case. for some values like '123456' it works and for some values like '98123456789' it does not work. that is why i thought the is a range for working this logic.

Comment: `TO_NUMBER('98123456789')` doesn't raise an error, so - no, that's not why your code won't work. Which error do you get, anyway? You never specified it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Summary: **NEVER** rely on implicit casts between data types.

---

> Is there a range of `VARCHAR2` which can be automatically convert to `NUMBER` in SQL?

Any `value` that can be implicitly cast from `VARCHAR2` to `NUMBER` is a something that can be successfully explicitly converted using `TO_NUMBER(value)` (with an implicit format model).

In general, this would match the regular expression:

```sql
[+-]?([0-9]+(D[0-9]*)?|D[0-9]+)([eE][+-][0-9]+)?
```

Where `D` is the decimal separator character specified by the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` session parameter.

There will be further limits as a `NUMBER` is only able to store (about) 38 digits but you may be able to convert larger strings and it will truncate the number beyond the precision of the number.

For example, given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT '0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '+00001234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '-00001234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '-00001234.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '-00001234.5678' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '.1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '.1234e4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '.1234E-004' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234E-004' FROM DUAL
```

Then you can explicitly perform a cast between data-types using the `CAST` function:

```sql
SELECT value, CAST(value AS NUMBER) FROM table_name;
```

Which (when the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` is `.,`) outputs:

| VALUE | CAST(VALUEASNUMBER) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| +00001234 | 1234 |
| -00001234 | -1234 |
| -00001234. | -1234 |
| -00001234.5678 | -1234.5678 |
| .1234 | .1234 |
| .1234e4 | 1234 |
| .1234E-004 | .00001234 |
| 1234E-004 | .1234 |

However, you should **NEVER** rely on implicitly casting between data types.

If we change the session parameters:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'France';
```

Then the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` changes from `.,` to `,`  and exactly the same query and same data:

```sql
SELECT value, CAST(value AS NUMBER) FROM table_name;
```

Now fails with `ORA-01722: invalid number` because it is now expecting decimal values to use `,` as the decimal point (as per the normal convention in France, and many other countries) rather than `.` and now all the strings with `.` are invalid.

Since any user can change their session parameters at any time then you cannot (and should not) rely on implicit conversion to always work.

If you want numbers that that will be valid for any session parameters then you cannot use a decimal separator and would be restricted to an integer significand and an optional exponent:

```sql
[+-]?[0-9]+([eE][+-][0-9]+)?
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mknN1GUI)